# Why flutter create does not work when running?

Tags: flutter

I amb trying to create the app, but when I run "flutter create name_app" it renders the following error:

Building flutter tool...

Running pub upgrade...

Please help. I tried running flutter doctor and I get the same error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an might be an issue with your flutter install. Follow [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) properly

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade fullter then run create app again and it worked perfectly.